# Oscilloscope over-current protection

Tags: current, oscilloscope

Ok, while I was going from a negative voltage to a positive voltage, I switched the leads connecting to the PSU. Normally this inverts the voltage, but I forgot I had it connected via BNC so all it did was connect the source to ground and the ground was hooked up to my oscilloscope channel input (1MOhm). I wanted to ask if this would have done any damage to the oscilloscope (current was 1.5A)? To me, the answer is no. But, I am trained in a different field and wanted to ask people who can comfort me because I have surprisingly never done that with a scope before :)

Also, I am used to scopes that can switch input impedance. I saw this answer in another topic, but I can get a 50 Ohm input impedance by using a splitter with a 50 Ohm termination, right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you had 1.5A flowing into the chassis ground of your scope via a BNC connector?  If that's correct, it is unlikely to have damaged anything.

A scope chassis is a protective earth, and should be able to handle enough fault current to pop a breaker, so 1.5A shouldn't cause damage.

As for the 50 ohm input, yes, you can use a BNC tee with a 50 ohm termination on it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, unless there was self heating in the wire your fine. Its not hard to send amps of current down your probe ground. If this becomes a habit for you get an oscilloscope with an isolated ground (which carries its own set of problems). I've shorted out some DC to DC converters on a ground on accident by not being too careful, and left scorch marks on the alligator clip.